# A way to stop hard deleted records to come in query results

Tags: apex, query

I'm querying deleted records in a query like below

```
Select Id, Name from Lead where isdeleted = true ALL ROWS
```

Records hard deleted from recycle bin using emptyrecyclebin() call still coming in the above query results. I read in different articles that Salesforce removes them in some time.

Is there any field filter available, that I can use in the above query to stop hard deleted records coming in the query results ?